# How do I conditionally suppress the inclusion of a module in Sphinx documentation indices

Tags: python, python-sphinx, documentation-generation

I have

```
   .. only:: some_build

      .. automodule:: some_module
         :members:
         :private-members:
```

in my Sphinx RST file; but even if `some_build` is false or absent, `some_module` appears in the index and list of modules generated by Sphinx (even though, as intended, no documentation is generated). The only way I seem to be able to suppress this is with `:noindex:` (but suppresses all indexing and cross-referencing even when `some_build` is true).

Is this the intended behavior? Is there a way to conditionally index a module documented with `auto module`?